# Check if JS box exists with RSpec + capybara-webkit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm using RSpec + capybara, and the capybara-webkit as driver.
I have to check if a JS box exists in the page after clicking on a button, but with no results.
If I use selenium as a driver, the test passes, but I need to use capybara-webkit.

I'm using

```
expect(page).to have_selector(#js_window)
```

My configuration is

```
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_selector = :css
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 1
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

RSpec.configure do |config|
 config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

Comment: It would help if you added more details of the driver config, test, and error message you're getting

Comment: Ok - so since you have run_server = false, this is a remote application you're attempting to run against.  HAve you turned on black/whitelisting in capybara-webkit and if so have you added the remote application to the whitelist in capybara-webkit configuration?  https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit#configuration

Comment: Yes, I also tried with `config.allow_unknown_urls` to be sure, but without results. I'm getting the error "expected #has_selector("#habla_topbar_div") to return true, got false", but when i'm using selenium as driver, it works.

Comment: Since it works in selenium it sounds like a config issue with capybara-WebKit but you haven't posted that. Have you tried setting your driver to :webkit_debug to see if that gives any hints?

Comment: In `Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|` I just have some allowed urls and `config.block_unknown_urls` . Should I add something else?

Comment: if you are using block_unknown_urls and are allowing all the urls needed for the page to render (or are just allowing all unknown urls rather than blocking them)  then I'm out of ideas --  try setting the driver to :webkit_debug instead of :webkit and see if it gives any clues as to whats happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was a problem with my config.block_unknown_urls (I was blocking the url I needed) and the default_max_wait_time (I changed it from 1 to 3).
Solved now!